# Fortran zlib Example Compilation on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compilation, fortran

I like using the [gzstream](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) library in C++ and would like similar functionality in Fortran77 code. However, my MWE doesn't find the references, and it is unclear to me if I have the correct Fortran wrapper installed.

There is documentation available at [DESY](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/linear_collider/users_guide_v4_dev/node22.html) for using zlib from Fortran but with no indication which zlib version it is referring to or how to obtain the Fortran wrapper.

I'd like to use standard packages as much as possible to make it easy to stay up to date.

Output of `dpkg -l 'zlib*'`:

```
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-===========
un  zlib1                       <none>             <none>             (no description available)
un  zlib1-dev                   <none>             <none>             (no description available)
ii  zlib1g:i386                 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubun i386               compression library - runtime
ii  zlib1g-dev:i386             1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubun i386               compression library - development
```

`zlib1-dev` has no installation candidate.

`dpkg -L zlib1g-dev:i386` shows the location of the static library as
`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.a`

Accordingly, to exclude library path issues, I am trying to compile with
`gfortran -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8 -O -Wall -Wtabs zlibtest.f /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.a`

I am obtaining

```
/tmp/ccWl8klj.o: In function `MAIN__':
zlibtest.f:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `gzopen_'
zlibtest.f:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `gzwrite_'
zlibtest.f:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to `gzclose_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My MWE code:

```
      program zlibtest
      implicit none

      integer ii
      integer fhandle, istat
      character*256 outline
      parameter (fhandle=0)

      call gzopen(fhandle, 'w', 'zlibtest.dat', istat)
      do ii=1,10
        write(outline, '(3i10)') ii, ii**2, ii**3
        call gzwrite(fhandle, outline)
      end do
      call gzclose(fhandle, istat)

      end program
```

Comment: There is a whole tag [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] about Fortran and C interoperability. The best thing to do is to use the Fortran 2003 standard C interoperability. Now you can try to compile with `-fno-underscoring` and see what happens, but I expect you still need to pass some variables by value. Plenty of duplicates in that tag I linked.

Comment: And BTW you probably want to interface the original C http://www.zlib.net/ library, not the C++ one.

Comment: Actually, why don't you try the zlib interface from https://genepi.qimr.edu.au/staff/davidD/#software ?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirF, definitely not thinking of using the C++ library, as that uses C++ streams, it was just an example for a wrapper. I was under the impression that a Fortran wrapper already existed from the [DESY] [1] page. What I'm really wondering is if that is describing the same zlib library, i.e. zlib.net since the function calls seem to deviate from the zlib.net documentation.
  [1]: https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/linear_collider/users_guide_v4_dev/node22.html